# Can someone please explain what exactly P(X>Y) means in probability?

Tags: probability

I know that $P(X<x)$ means " probability of random events for which random probability $X$ is smaller than $x$ (real number).  What means $P(X+Y)$, $P(X/Y)$, $P(X>Y)$. Example would help. Thank you very much

Comment: $P(X>Y)$ is just "probability that $X$ is bigger than $Y$." For example, if we each roll a die, and $X$ is the number you roll, and $Y$ is the number I roll, then $P(X>Y)$ is the probability that you roll a larger number than I do. The other two expressions ($P(X+Y)$ and $P(X/Y)$) don't make sense.

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure it doesnt make sense? In school we have problem : find distribution F of sum X1+X2, where X1, X2 are independet random probab. There also is solution: P(X1+X2<=y)=double integral though area - small! x1+x2<=y....

Comment: P(X+Y) and P(X+Y < z) - not the same.  P(X+Y < z) makes sense, P(X+Y) does not

Comment: So P(X+Y<z) would for example mean: probab. that sum of me rolling the dice and you rolling the dice is smaller than z?

Comment: Indeed, $P(X+Y)$ has no meaning.  Try reading it out loud: "the probability that X plus Y".  It is a sentence without a verb.